# Using httpGet in a thread to send the latest update to a website

Tags: android, multithreading, httpclient

I have the following problem:

- My application needs to inform a website of a change as fast as possible
- This can happen so fast that the previous webrequest hasn't been completely dealt with
- The application should always send at least the last webrequest (it doesn't matter if previous ones are lost).

I'm not sure how to do this optimally. My current method is below, but gives me a warning (*"Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated."*). I suspect I can reuse this connection, but have no clue how. Using *threadSafeConnManager* doesn't seem to be the solution, since I only need one connection (I think :) ).

How should I optimize my code for my needs?

The runnable in the code below is in a thread (*webThread*) and *webrequest* is a global variable that gets set to a certain url. After setting the variable, *webThread.run()* is fired.

```
private Runnable mSyncInternet = new Runnable() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

    public void run() {

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(webrequest);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            sendMessageToUI(MSG_NO_INTERNET, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            sendMessageToUI(MSG_NO_INTERNET, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just today I found a [blog](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/05/05/fixing-the-invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-connection-still-allocated-problem/) with the solution to the SingleClientConnManager issue:

```
public static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();

    client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, 
            mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);

    return client;
}
```

I tried it, and it worked perfectly!

Comment: If I understand correctly, this rotates connections (up to 20). If possible, I think I would like to use one connection. Also, I'm not sure if I can then get that the last webrequest is sent as last. But I will try, so thanks! :D

Comment: Well if you just want to use one connection, make sure that you consume all the response body before you reuse the connection.

Comment: the threadsafeclientconnmanager option makes my app unresponsive.

Comment: I'll see how I can reuse the connection. Do you have any suggestions for my current thread structure? Because I'm not sure that it is the best way

Comment: Maybe you have too many connections and it will take a while for them to be released (check your logcat). Your option then is to make sure you finish one request before you launch another, maybe using SharedPreferences you can achieve that.